# How to display the column value in MMYYYY in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a complex sql query given to me by my colleague. I want to get one column in `MMYYYY` format. How can I achieve it? Following is the column part in query (the query is too long. so I am pasting only the column part).

```
CASE
   WHEN len(datepart (WEEK, cast(cast(month(from_date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + cast(xx.day_val AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + cast(year(from_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME))) = 1 
   THEN '0' + datepart (WEEK, cast(cast(month(from_date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + cast(xx.day_val AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + cast(year(from_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME))
   ELSE datepart (WEEK, cast(cast(month(from_date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + cast(xx.day_val AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + cast(year(from_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME))
END AS week_number
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to format as MMYYYY?

Comment: week_number as you can see after the END statement.

Comment: You wish to format week_number (which is an int between 1 and 52) in the format MMYYYY?

Comment: actually it is a datetime format which is being cast as varchar.

Comment: So you wanna return a week_number follow with a year? like 502012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only retain date in specific format if you store the date as a string (char/varchar) not as datetime / date.

To display date / datetime in a specific format, you need to use CONVERT or CAST:

SELECT CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(datetime, '2010-03'), 103)
-- 03/2010

**Reference:** http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes (i hope that this will answer your question)

Regards,

Nicholas